# How do I put this in the form of the function in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, function, foreach

How do I put this in the form of the function in Codeigniter?

model, controller and view

```
    public function seasons_of_serie($id_movie){

    $this->db->group_by("num_season"); 
    $this->db->where('movie',$id_movie);
    $query = $this->db->get('seasons');

    foreach($query->result() as $row){

        $num_season =  $row->num_season;

        echo $num_season."<hr>";

        $this->db->where('movie',$id_movie);
        $this->db->where('num_season',$num_season);
        $query_ep =  $this->db->get('seasons');

        foreach($query_ep->result() as $row_ep){
            echo $row_ep->title_ep.'<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

http://www9.0zz0.com/2014/01/05/17/392723425.png

Comment: No, this code is not a controller, neither model nor view

Comment: I think you should restart from the MVC pattern...what you need to do?

Comment: I want to make it knead

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Turning the results of this function to the system mvc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a point of start for the MVC pattern.

Controller:

```
<?php
    public function seasons_of_serie($id_movie)
    {
        //Load the model
        $this->load->model('model_name', '' , TRUE);
        $data['season'] = $this->model_name->seasons_of_serie();
        $this->load->view('view_name', $data);
    }
?>
```

Model: (this is just the function, not the full model file)

```
<?php
public function seasons_of_serie($id_movie){

   $this->db->group_by("num_season"); 
    $this->db->where('movie',$id_movie);
    $query = $this->db->get('seasons');

    foreach($query->result() as $row){

        $num_season =  $row->num_season;

        //echo $num_season."<hr>";

        $this->db->where('movie',$id_movie);
        $this->db->where('num_season',$num_season);
        $query_ep =  $this->db->get('seasons');

         return $query_ep->result();
        //foreach($query_ep->result() as $row_ep){
        //    echo $row_ep->title_ep.'<br>';
        //}
    }
}
?>
```

View:

```
<?php
var_dump($season);
?>
```

Comment: Christian Giupponi I'll try Thank you

Comment: Why are you trying to implement "My Very Code" pattern?

Comment: You are very, very close
But the results that I got as a picture in which I will put

Comment: http://www9.0zz0.com/2014/01/05/17/392723425.png

Comment: @teresko are you talking to me?

Answer (score 0):

Convert what you have into a model. First off, you should have no outputs in the model so replace all the echo lines into something that goes inside a return variable, or just a set of data that will be forwarded to a view by the controller. You might also want to optimize your queries a bit.

The view should be the presentational part, I guess HTML with the results of your function properly formatted.

And the controller should call the model function, get the data, and send the data to the view. Also, modifications of the model data should be done here.

I'd strongly suggest you learn about MVC a bit more before following these rough guidelines.

Comment: This is what I want, but adjusts the results are not as I want.

Comment: @medsaid What do you mean?